# C# vs PowerShell. How to get detailed exception info?

Tags: c#, powershell, exception, comexception

I'm using some external library though COM interface.
I have generic class for that.

```
Database.Connector connector = new Database.Connector();
string connectString = "srvr=nonexisthost;database=test;"; // bogus connect string
try
{
    var database = connector.Connect(connectString);
}
catch (COMException ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Trying to build a error proof logic I intentionally provoke an exception.

And I have discovered that C# COMException contains only generic info, like:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

while executing samey code in PowerShell results in more detailed description:

```
$connector = New-Object -ComObject Database.Connector
$connectString = "srvr=nonexisthost;database=test;"
$database = $connector.Connect($connectString)
```

> Error while executing transaction with an information base
>   server_addr=nonexisthost descr=11001(0x00002AF9): Host is unknown. 
>   line=1048 file=src\DataExchangeCommon.cpp

My question is: what should I do in order to get same error info in C# (if it is possible)?

Comment: Can you show your related powershell code?

Comment: Your server address is non existent.  Open DataExcehngeCommon.cpp and find out what is at line 1048.

Comment: @jdweng no way. It is closed source proprietary lib. So I'm using it as is.

Comment: @RyanSchlueter done.

Comment: @OlexandrSytnyk: what is the actual type of the exception you're getting? Does it have additional properties you could read? Does it have an inner exception? What is says?

Comment: cpp is always readable text.  It is source c plus code.

Comment: @abatishchev I'm getting System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException type exception. All error codes are generic and innerExcetion is null.

Comment: What type you're getting in PowerShell? Are you sure you're using the exact same types? I see you're adding `-Com` what means some special wrapper by PowerShell. And apparently this wrapper works differently than the one in .NET.

Comment: @abatishchev afaik -Com is a short form for -ComObject as they produce the same result, according to get-member.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a COM Interop expert but I'll try to answer what I know and hope it will help you.

### From the managed side

If the HRESULT is recognized by the runtime (CLR), the runtime automatically creates a specific managed exception for the error (e.g. FileNotFoundException). Otherwise, the runtime creates a generic COMException object which says "I don't know what this HRESULT meaning".

If the unmanaged code provides error info, you will see it in the ErrorCode property, otherwise, you will see just the HRESULT code.
You can try to search for this code (google\github) to obtain more info.

### From the unmanaged side

You need to implement ISupportErrorInfo and IErrorInfo interfaces to provide more info.

**So to answer your question**, in C#, you can't get more info in the COMException object if this info is not provided.

For more info:
[COMException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception?view=netframework-4.7.2), [Handling COM Interop Exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/handling-com-interop-exceptions), [IErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-ierrorinfo), [ISupportErrorInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/oaidl/nn-oaidl-isupporterrorinfo), [HRESULT's mapping](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-map-hresults-and-exceptions), [Common HRESULT values](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/desktop/SecCrypto/common-hresult-values)

Comment: So you suggest that powershell executable is using non-conventional means to get error info that is unavailable in pure c#?

Comment: @Olexandr It's interesting me also but unfortunately I'm not familiar with powershell runtime so I can't answer on this question.